# SharePoint 2010 Drop down menu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create one Site with 2 sub-sites on SharePoint 2010.

It should look similar to this: [See sample](http://www.heathersolomon.com/images/postimages/sampledropnav.gif)

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint Foundation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps -

1. Come to the root site, by following the bread crumb tool you have.
2. Go to Site Actions -> Create Site and name it 'Site 1'. Your parent site of 'Site 1' is created now.
3. Go to 'Site 1'. Click 'Create Site' and name it 'Sub Site 1'. Your first sub site is created.
4. Go to 'Site 1' again and click on 'Create Site' and name it 'Site 1 page'. Your second sub site is created.
5. Go to 'Site 1'. Click on Site Actions -> site settings -> modify all site settings.
6. Click on Navigation under 'Look and Feel'.
7. Select the check box 'Show sub sites' and click OK.

Your subsites menu should be ready. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I think "Look and Feel" has to do with SharePoint 2007. 
On step 6. We must just click on "Show subsites" checkbox under "Global Naviagation". 

Thank You, without your help I would not get it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement and ended up adding a 3rd party control for a footer menu (we ended up with too many items in root top menu), we got it from QIPoint. Hope this helps someone else thought ide share that, good luck